# 'router-outlet' is not a known element Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Repo: https://github.com/leongaban/lifeleveler.io

Not sure why I'm getting this error, I have Router imported in my app.component.ts

I'm trying to use the `app.component` to hold the main `<router-outlet>`, and serve up the login view first.

[image]

#### app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthService } from './shared/services/auth.service';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './shared/models/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

#### app.component.html

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

#### app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: I'm quite new to Angular2 myself. I'd try adding `RouterModule` to your app.module NgModule imports

Comment: your code is fine, ido you have some plunker of this

Comment: I just tried it, still the same error :(

Comment: there is no problem in this code. don't import `routing` and `RouterModule` beacuse `routing` is the same as `RouterModule` with some configuration

Comment: Sometimes I have to stop `ng serve` and restart it for an error to go away. It always confuses the hell out of me

Comment: I'm still using systemjs atm so npm start, done that. Here is my repo, will make plunkr soon. https://github.com/leongaban/lifeleveler.io

Comment: can't found your problem do you want me add wepack to your project instead of system.js

Comment: @Bougarfaoui Sure, still not sure how webpack loaders work/do :) Yeah no idea what is going on. Wait did you `npm start` it fine?

Comment: you gonna wrok with the new @angular/cli don't worry it's easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just refactored your project with webpack , your same code works just fine:

[github repo](https://github.com/bougarfaoui/app)

first :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

npm install 

ng serve
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm I forked and downloaded it, `npm install` then had to update the angular-cli.json with new environment stuff from the warning, but now getting this error on ng serve `ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined`

Comment: `ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined`

Comment: Checking this, because this is the answer, even though I couldn't get the app the run. Angular-CLI is the way to go with building new ng2 apps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be importing the RouterModule multiple times.

I would remove this line from your `app.routing.ts`

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

In your `app.module` I would import your routes with:

```
import { routes } from './app.routing';
```

And then import the `RouterModule` as:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` statement inside your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and remove it from your `app.routing.ts` file:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: Still not working :( making a plnkr now but my app.component.html isn't loading, making a new question for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674180/failed-to-load-app-component-html-in-plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Just import RouterOutlet

```
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
```