# Failed to load app.component.html in Plnkr

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, plnkr.co

Plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/910M73kwYKc8xPlSIU57?p=preview

[image]

Directory:

[image]

#### app.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
// import { AuthService } from './shared/services/auth.service';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        // LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        // AuthService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('oninit')
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have `app.component.ts` in your plunkr..

Comment: @PankajParkar oh sorry in this starter kit they called it just app.ts so I stuck with that. Fixed the path in `app.module` to look at `app` but still not loading the html :(

Comment: Oh app is their app.module, realized my mistake, making a new plnkr

Comment: Ok fixed, but still getting that error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not tech support for Plnkr.

Comment: ??? This is a valid Stackoverflow question, and it just got answered :p plnkr is just like SublimeText or VisualStudio, Webstorm what have you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular can't resolve relative path of `app.component.html`.
Just replace `./app.component.html` with `src/app.component.html` and you are good to go.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        ngOnInit() {
            console.log('oninit')
        }
    }
```

There are other alternatives to do this 
 but `angular-cli` or `webpack` handles relative path on their own which are more preferrable.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm now getting a new error, will make a new question `Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https://run.plnkr.co/app`

Comment: Mind a look? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676066/error-systemjs-xhr-error-404-in-angular2-plnkr