# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) in Angular2 Plnkr

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, plnkr.co

#### The error:

[image]

https://plnkr.co/edit/910M73kwYKc8xPlSIU57?p=preview

#### index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Angular 2.1.2 + TypeScript Starter Kit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.9/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.41/dist/system.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/typescript@2.1.4/lib/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Directory

[image]

app (the app.module)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
// import { AuthService } from './shared/services/auth.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    // AuthService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

Renamed my `config` to `src/config` but error remains.

Comment: Have you tried my answer​ below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `/` with `.` in your `<base href="/">` `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href=".">
  <title>Angular 2.1.2 + TypeScript Starter Kit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.9/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.41/dist/system.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/typescript@2.1.4/lib/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```